# How to reduce Swift enum conversion code

Tags: swift, generics, core-data, enums

I have a variety of enums such as below.

```
enum PaperOrientation : Int { case portrait, landscape }
enum MetricType : Int { case inches, metric }
```

I made the enums of type Int, so that the values of instances could be saved as numbers with CoreData.

When retrieving the values from CoreData to use in the program, I end up with very similar conversion routines, like those shown below.

Typically, I want some default value - such as for the case where it is a new enum for the latest version of the program, and a value for that variable may not actually have been saved in CoreData.  For example, the MetricType was added for the second rev of the program.  Retrieving a paper created in rev 1 will not have a metric value saved.  For the nil value, I want to use a default value the paper was originally assumed to have.

```
class ConversionRoutine {

    class func orientationFor(_ num: NSNumber?) -> PaperOrientation {
        if let iVal = num?.intValue {
            if let val = PaperOrientation(rawValue: iVal) {
                return val
            }
        }
        return PaperOrientation(rawValue: 0)!
    }

    class func metricTypeFor(_ num: NSNumber?) -> MetricType {
        if let iVal = num?.intValue {
            if let val = MetricType(rawValue: iVal) {
                return val
            }
        }
        return MetricType(rawValue: 0)!
    }
}
```

Is there a way to reduce the redundancy?

I present a way below that works pretty well.  But welcome more refinements or improvements.

Comment: `return PaperOrientation(rawValue: num?.intValue ?? 0) ?? .portrait`

Comment: or instead of declaring your num an optional NSNumber just assign a default value for it  `func orientationFor(_ num: NSNumber = 0)` and `return PaperOrientation(rawValue: num.intValue) ?? .portrait`

Comment: Some of the conversion routines could be cleaned up.  I like the one-liner in the first reply.  But mainly, I was interested in reducing the amount of code overall - which I have found, so far, to be done with protocol extensions in the answer below.  Also, in this particular case, I was concerned with data coming from CoreData, where the data is an optional.  For one of my apps, I had maybe 30 (and growing) cases of converting data from CoreData.  So far, creating an IntDefaultable protocol has really simplified defining and using new cases.  But still looking for potential improvements.

Answer (score 3):

The Swift 4 example below uses a Defaultable protocol based on RawRepresentable.  The first step is creating a defaultValue that can be used when the initializer fails.  Note that the Defaultable protocol is not limited to Int enums.  A String enum could also use it.

```
protocol Defaultable : RawRepresentable {
    static var defaultValue : Self { get }
}

protocol IntDefaultable : Defaultable where RawValue == Int {
}

extension IntDefaultable {
    static func value(for intValue : Int) -> Self {
        return Self.init(rawValue: intValue) ?? Self.defaultValue
    }

    static func value(for num : NSNumber?) -> Self {
        if let iVal = num?.intValue {
            return self.value(for: iVal)
        }
        return Self.defaultValue
    }
}
```

After the Defaultable protocol is defined, I can create an IntDefaultable protocol that will be used for Int enums.

In an extension to IntDefaultable, I can create the generic code to handle the conversion.  First, I create a function that takes an Int.  Then I create a function that takes an NSNumber optional.

Next, look at how one of the enums is built:

```
enum MetricType : Int, Codable, IntDefaultable { case inches, metric
    static var defaultValue: MetricType = .inches
}
```

I also decided to declare the enum Codable, which may be useful.  When I add the IntDefaultable protocol, it becomes fairly easy to add the defaultValue line of code with code completion - go to the new line and type “def”-tab, then “ = .”, and then choose one of the values from the popup.  Note that often I want to pick the first enum value, but the default value could be any one.

The last thing is calling the conversion routine for getting a value from CoreData

```
let units = MetricType.value(for: self.metricType)  // where self.metricType is the NSManagedObject member.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an initializer in `enum`.

```
enum PaperOrientation : Int { 
    case portrait, landscape

    init(number: NSNumber) {
        self = PaperOrientation(rawValue: number.intValue) ?? .portrait
    }
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus Sorry, I forgot to change type to `NSNumber`. It will be meaningful in this case.

Comment: The issue here is CoreData store Int to NSNumber and the default initializer can't use NSNumber with default case. I believe this is the best approach.

Comment: @LeoDabus Why should I use nil coalescing even we need a default value? It will be much simpler to use `default` case.